# add value if cell null c# dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[C# winform] I want to fit value into Cells of DataGridView if Cell empty , help me

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3van.png)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I just joined

Comment: Show us your code what you have done so far, otherwise it is difficult for us to help you.

Comment: <code>
for(int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < dgv.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value==null)
                    {
                        dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = "0";
                    }
                }
            }
</code>

Comment: What happens when you run that code snippet?

Comment: You need to remove `&&` from the Condition and use `¦¦` instead.

Comment: I tried, but not possible.:(

Comment: The compound “if” statement in the picture is “broken.” The first compound condition in the ‘if’ statement is: `if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null`… let us assume `Value` IS “null”. If `Value` IS “null”, then this first condition will return “true” then the code will obligingly attempt to test the second condition of the compound ‘if’ statement `dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString()`… which will obviously fail and throw the error in the picture. To make this work correctly, you need to change the `==` to `!=` when checking for the null value.

Answer (score 0):

Taken straight from the comments on your question but in a readable format:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < dgv.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null)
        {
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

I see no reason that won't work, if it did work please let people know so future people with a similar problem can use it.

I suggest changing `dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null` to `string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value)`, it ensure that value can never be `""` which isn't null but would appear empty.